# iPhone showing reminders, but I have none

Tags: iphone, reminders

My Reminders app is showing 6 reminders, but as far as I know, I have none. I've checked the completed file, checked in iCal on the Mac. Any ideas how to delete these reminders?

Comment: Reminders don't appear in iCal. They appear in the Reminders app in Mountain Lion. If you have iCloud enabled, you could always log into iCloud.com

Comment: What happens when you try to delete the reminders?

Answer (score 2):

When you open the Reminders app, make sure there isn't anything set in both Reminders *and* Tasks.

You may have created a *Task* using Siri, or another app by accident. And as a result of the way the app is setup on the iPhone, it doesn't default to showing you both Reminders and Tasks at the same time.

On the iPhone try the following:

1. Open up the Reminders app
2. Tap near the bottom of the screen (you should see other white tabs)
3. Tap on whichever tab is not active (most likely Tasks)
4. If there are any items listed there, check them off by tapping the circles next to the name

On the Mac try the following:

1. Open up the Reminders app
2. Ensure sidebar is visible by going to View > Show Sidebar in the top Menu Bar
3. Click on all of the different options in the sidebar (Today, Reminders, Tasks, etc)
4. If there are any items listed there, check them off by clicking the circles next to the name

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue before.  Turn off all reminders and turn them back on to reset the reminder data.

1. Go to **Settings** - **Mail, Contacts, Calendars**.
2. For each listed account, select it and switch **Reminders** to **OFF**.
3. Restart your iPhone for good measure.
4. Go to **Settings** - **Mail, Contacts, Calendars**.
5. for each desired account, select it and switch **Reminders** to **ON**.

Comment: Just tried that & they are still there. The closest Apple store is a 56 hour round trip, but the next time I'm in the vicinity, I'll stop in & try the genius bar. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I’ve found that **Reminders** sync in iOS can be pretty flaky. Especially after a reboot, they usually stop syncing down.

What I do is create a dummy reminder on my iPhone or iPad, then wait for it to upload. Within a few seconds, the app should pull down its correct state, and update accordingly.